# Continuous replication across a VPN with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, vpn

I am working  with a project that uses `CouchDB` I am new in that technologie.

I  have to copy a local database to an external server in a continuous mode, let say the I have to copy database:

> reviews

I have been reading that I can do something like this:

[image]

The issue I have is that I need to use a VPN in order to access to the local database `reviews` so my question is:
How can I replicate a local database whose uses a VPN to a remote database in continuous mode?